# How to fetch last row of a webtable in selenium

Tags: selenium

I have a webtable for which I have to fetch the last row . The problem is that the webtable is dynamic so I don't know the row number.I have tried below code but the row number is static there which will fail.

```
List<WebElement> rows=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[1]/tbody/tr[5]"));
```

Comment: Can you get us a sample URL? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

to get last element use `(locator)[last()]` method, like:

```
WebElement lastRow =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table[1]/tbody/tr)[last()]"));
```

which is shorted variant of:

```
(locator)[position() = last()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LastRowFetching {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        WebDriver driver;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G://chromedriver.exe");
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://money.rediff.com/gainers/bsc/dailygroupa?");         
        //No.of rows 
        List  rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")); 
        System.out.println("No of rows are : " + rows.size());
        int lastRow = rows.size();

        WebElement lastRowFetch =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='leftcontainer']/table/tbody/tr/td["+lastRowcount+"])"));
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`int lastRowcount=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[1]/tbody/")).findElements(By.tagName("tr")).size();

    WebElement Lastrow =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[1]/tbody/tr["+lastRowcount+"]"));`

In first Line we get the Last Row count from the table.

On second line we get the Last row Element from the table.

Comment: Maybe you could extend your answer with a little bit of text and explanation... In this state it's not really helpful at all.