# How to choose a result in a dynamic webtable that has the same name and later timing in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I have been working on a Selenium project in Python where I want to choose the result which has a later timing than the earlier one but have trouble implementing it. What I meant is this,

**Example**

[image]

if I have a dynamic webtable with results of the same exact name(which in this case is job order number), how do I implement the function to choose the result which has been created the latest?

**Test.py**

```
def __init__(self,driver):
    self.driver = driver

def testing(self):
    #For the 1st result with the same name with earlier timing
    result1_xpath = "//body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[8]/div[1]"
    #For the 2nd result with the same name with later timing
    result2_xpath = "//body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[8]/div[1]"
```

**HTML Code**

```html
 <table id="table" role="table" aria-busy="false" aria-colcount="10" aria-describedby="table__caption_" class="table b-table table-striped table-hover table-sm b-table-stacked-md"><!----><!----><thead role="rowgroup" class=""><!----><tr role="row" class=""><th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="1" class=""><div>request id</div></th><th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="2" class=""><div>job order number</div></th><th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="3" class=""><div>status</div></th><th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="4" class=""><div>requestor</div></th><th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="5" class=""><div>approver</div></th><th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="6" class=""><div>Total amounts ($)</div></th><th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="7" class=""><div>Total Number of cards</div></th><th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="8" class=""><div>Request DateTime</div></th><th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="9" class=""><div>Update DateTime</div></th><th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-colindex="10" class=""><div> Rejection Reason</div></th></tr></thead><tbody role="rowgroup"><!----><tr role="row" tabindex="0" aria-rowindex="1" class=""><td aria-colindex="1" data-label="request id" role="cell" class=""><div>101</div></td><td aria-colindex="2" data-label="job order number" role="cell" class=""><div>ecTesting2</div></td><td aria-colindex="3" data-label="status" role="cell" class=""><div>Topup_Completed</div></td><td aria-colindex="4" data-label="requestor" role="cell" class=""><div>zivwang</div></td><td aria-colindex="5" data-label="approver" role="cell" class=""><div>zivwang</div></td><td aria-colindex="6" data-label="Total amounts ($)" role="cell" class=""><div>4.00</div></td><td aria-colindex="7" data-label="Total Number of cards" role="cell" class=""><div>4</div></td><td aria-colindex="8" data-label="Request DateTime" role="cell" class=""><div>29/01/2021 15:32:04</div></td><td aria-colindex="9" data-label="Update DateTime" role="cell" class=""><div>29/01/2021 15:36:07</div></td><td aria-colindex="10" data-label=" Rejection Reason" role="cell" class=""><div></div></td></tr><tr role="row" tabindex="0" aria-rowindex="2" class=""><td aria-colindex="1" data-label="request id" role="cell" class=""><div>102</div></td><td aria-colindex="2" data-label="job order number" role="cell" class=""><div>ecTesting2</div></td><td aria-colindex="3" data-label="status" role="cell" class=""><div>Returned</div></td><td aria-colindex="4" data-label="requestor" role="cell" class=""><div>zivwang</div></td><td aria-colindex="5" data-label="approver" role="cell" class=""><div>zivwang</div></td><td aria-colindex="6" data-label="Total amounts ($)" role="cell" class=""><div>4.00</div></td><td aria-colindex="7" data-label="Total Number of cards" role="cell" class=""><div>4</div></td><td aria-colindex="8" data-label="Request DateTime" role="cell" class=""><div>29/01/2021 15:35:21</div></td><td aria-colindex="9" data-label="Update DateTime" role="cell" class=""><div>29/01/2021 16:44:41</div></td><td aria-colindex="10" data-label=" Rejection Reason" role="cell" class=""><div>Wrong top up amount</div></td></tr><!----><!----></tbody><!----></table>
```

Comment: add your html , also is the list already displayed in sorted order ?

Comment: @TecGeek the table Element HTML please add that

Comment: my website doesn't collectively extract HTML as a whole. In that case I only can extract based on the element I select within the result. Is that fine? For this instance should I select the `job Order Request` element or `Request DateTime` element for both results?

Comment: yes try adding that ,

Comment: create `xpath` which gets all rows in table and later in Python use `[-1]` to get last row.

Comment: you don't have to use all tags in `xpath` - especially don't use `tbody` which may not exists but `Chrome` may display it in `DevTools`. ie. `//table[1]//tr[2]/td[8]/div`

Comment: @furas Like this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944834/how-to-fetch-last-row-of-a-webtable-in-selenium/44946398

Comment: did you try `[last()]`? First you may try `xpath` to get only `tr` with `[last()]` and later use another `xpath` to get `div` in previous result. OR you may try to use `( )` in `xpath` to run all with one `xpath`.

Comment: it would be simpler if you would add minimal working code with real URL - so we could copy and run it and test solutions.

Comment: it's not public since it contains proprietor's data etc

Comment: @furas Can you show me how to implement it? I'm stuck in the mud right now

Comment: I don't have example data for this. And we all are too lazy to create fake data for example. And this is why you should always in question add url for your page.

Comment: If you don't have example data then we don't can't create code for this example. If you can't add URL then you may copy HTML and add this to question. Eventually share HTML on pastebin.com or Google Drive.

Comment: I have added the `HTML` script. Please check it out